# Question on CSS % height

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari

If I define a CSS as follows;

```
div {height: 50%;}
```

Will this work across most modern desktop browsers (IE8+, FF, Safari) and mobile browsers (iPhone/iPad, etc)

Is there any need to specify the following 2 additional attributes for cross-browser support

```
min-height: 50%; height: auto;
```

I am asking this question in the context of fluid design (i.e. same page will scale for multiple devices...desktop/tablet/mobile)..So please let me know what should be the preferred approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need those.

BUT: Height is only relative to the parent. And the parent by default has no height (more accurately it's the height of the children inside it).

So you need:

```
body,html { height: 100%; }
```

So specify a "starting" height, and you may need to keep the "height chain" alive as well.

The reason for min-height instead of height is that height is fixed - it can't get bigger than that no matter what is inside it. This may not work right. So instead people do min-height so it's as least as tall as they want, but is allowed to grow.

The trouble with min-height is that it doesn't work on all browsers.

Comment: Thx a lot...So using just "height" attribute in % val, will the same page scale well for multiple devices...desktop/tablet/mobile ?

Comment: Height doesn't make it scale. So no. Different machines have different heights, so your content will fit on some and not on others. Why do you even want to specify the height?

Comment: I am trying to create a fluid layout..so nothing can be specified in fixed/px value ...We do need to explicitly specify the "height" property in lot of places (e.g. for some overflow)...So my question is will this % height work across multiple platforms ?

Comment: The height is relative to the height of the *device*. I quite doubt that the height of the content has any relationship to the height of the device! You most definitely can use px values for fluid layouts! If the size of your content is fixed (i.e. a fixed number of lines, or letters) then specify the height as fixed. If you don't know the height in advance, then specify nothing and let the browser decide. You say will it "work", but you don't define "work". It will work in terms of fixing the height, sure. But I doubt that's what you actually want.